# TabHost pass Parameter in CreateIntentFor<>

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-tabhost, xamarin, mvvmcross

After downloading the newest Version of mvvmcross (V3) I had some work to do, to upgrade some of my projects to the new state. Last thing I'm not able to fulfill is to pass a parameter to the viewmodel from the tabhost. In the older versions it worked fine (but it was different) and now I got an error.

But First here the Code (Line 19 makes trouble (**watch comment in code**), Line 18 works but only without Parameters):

```
[Activity]
public class MainActivity : MvxTabActivity
{
    public new MainViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (MainViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
        set { base.ViewModel = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnViewModelSet()
    {
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;

        spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec("listeaktiv");
        spec.SetIndicator(App.indicatorActive, Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.green));
        //spec.SetContent(this.CreateIntentFor(ViewModel.ListViewModel)); -> It works (But only without Parameters! How could I pass them here?)
        spec.SetContent(this.CreateIntentFor<ListViewModel>(new { parameter = App.indicatorActive })); //Exception (on the next Line)
        TabHost.AddTab(spec);
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
    }
}
```

(App.indicatorActive is the Parameter I want to pass, its in the App.cs: (`public static string indicatorActive = "Active";`)

My ListViewModel looks like that:

```
public class ListViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
        public ListViewModel(string parameter)
        {

        }
}
```

Error:

```
Unhandled Exception:
Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to load ViewModel for type 
INApplikationsMonitor.Core.ViewModels.ListViewModel from locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator
```

Comment: can you add a few more comments - you have two SetContent lines - which one works, which one doesn't (saying 'Line 18' doesn't really help me - sorry, but can't be bothered to count!). Is the error for the commented out code? Or for the uncommented code? Sorry - just confused by whether the error is for the live code, or the commented code or for something else...

Comment: The First SetContent works fine (But only without Parameters, here I don't know how to pass them) and the Second SetContent doesn't work (its with parameters).. it gives me the error

Comment: With Comment in Code, I meant the "Text" not the commented code itself - sry for the confusion

Comment: Sorry - the code posted is really confusing me - but I've posted what I think the answer is. Also, for the unhandled exception you should also be able to get hold of the inner exception for trace - e.g. use `.ToLongString()` to trace the full exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My **guess** is that this is just because you are using the old ViewModel lifecycle.

In v3:

- the ViewModel constructor parameters are used for IoC - for Dependency Injection of services.
- for passing parameters you need to instead use an `Init` method within the ViewModel

For more on this, see: http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/v3-new-viewmodel-lifecycle.html :

> The default ViewModelLocator in v3 builds new ViewModel instances using a 4-step process - CIRS:
>
> - Construction - using IoC for Dependency Injection
> - Init() - initialisation of navigation parameters
> - ReloadState() - rehydration after tombstoning
> - Start() - called when initialisation and rehydration are complete